# How can I add custom classes to GWT project outside of EntryPoint

Tags: java, inheritance, model-view-controller, gwt, controller

I have to take a JavaFX application and translate it into a GWT implementation but I don't fully understand some of the structure of a GWT application.

In my entrypoint class I create all the gwt elements I need, but I want to include some other classes to add some functionality. However whenever I try to compile the GWT project I end up with the following error.

```
[ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

The src structure is:

```
src.com.Application
 |
 +-- Client
 |  |  
 |  +-- Application
 |  +-- ApplicationService
 |  +-- ApplicationServiceAsync
 |    
 +-- Controller
 |  |  
 |  +-- ParameterController
 |  +-- PopupController
 |    
 +-- Server
 |  |  
 |  +-- ApplicationServiceImpl
```

My `Application.gwt.xm`l file looks like this:

```
<module rename-to="Application">

    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                  -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>             -->

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                   -->
    <entry-point class='com.Application.client.Application'/>

    <!--Specify the GWT style sheet                           -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

    <!-- Specify the app servlets.                   -->
    <servlet path='/ApplicationService' class='com.Application.server.ApplicationServiceImpl'/>

    <source path="com.Application.Controllers.ParameterController" />
</module>
```

If I remove all references of `ParameterController.java` in `Application.java` and comment out the source tag in my `Application.gwt.xm` file it compiles and opens in chrome with all empty elements without any functionality.

How can I allow for the code outside of `Application.java` be usable in my gwt project? Is there some specific class `ParameterController.java` must inherit to be compile-able, if so what?

Answer (score 0):

The client package is only added for compilation if you dont specify any `<source/>` element, because the default is `<source path="Client">`.
In your example the only code that will be compiled by the GWT compiler(and usable on client-side) is your `ParameterController`.
By also adding `<source path="Client">` to your `*.gwt.xml` file the problem should be fixed.
(Also the package names should not use capitol letters.)